# Angular momentum operator for 2 dimensions?

Tags: angular-momentum, dirac-equation, spinors

Recently I get the task to build (2 + 1)-Dirac theory. I wrote corresponding Dirac equation in a form
$$
(i\sigma_{0}\partial_{0} + i\sigma_{1}\partial_{1} + i\sigma_{2}\partial_{2} - m)\Psi = 0,
$$
where
$$
\sigma_{0} = \sigma_{y}, \quad \sigma_{1} = i\sigma_{x}, \quad \sigma_{2} = i\sigma_{z}, \quad [\sigma^{\mu}, \sigma^{\nu}]_{+} = 2g^{\mu \nu}, \quad g^{\mu \nu} = diag (1, -1, -1).
$$
Many operators, such as inversion, charge conjugation and other I can find without problems. But I can't get angular momentum operator, because I can't understand what operator I need to find. In two spatial dimensions I can get only the operator of projection of angular momentum, isn't it? Anyway, how to find it, if I haven't corresponding Lorentz group transformation law in (2 + 1)? Can I associate it with rotations on a plane?

Comment: Mimic the arguments used in the $3+1$ dimensional case. Open a book like Itzykson & Zuber, if necessary. Don't forget that the Pauli matrices are the $(2+1)$ dimensional gamma matrices. Remember that the angular momentum operator has three components, one corresponding to spatial rotations and two from boosts.

Comment: @Suresh : but I thought that Lorentz boosts is connected with center of energy vector (is creates angular momentum 4-tensor with angular momentum vector in 3D case).

Comment: I like to think of Lorentz boosts taking one inertial frame to another. Further, think of $2+1$ dimensions as coming from $3+1$ dimensions, where you ignore a third spatial dimension.